# unable to change ion-header's Background-Color in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I Have an Ionic2 project and I want to change `ion-header` is Background-color.
I Have tried `[ngStyle]`, CSS selector and ETC...

here is the Project:
https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/tree/Medicine-Component-Created
Here is the code:

https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/blob/Medicine-Component-Created/src/pages/Medicine/Medicine.html

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First add your color to src/theme/variables.scss

   example:

   `$colors: ( ..., blusky: #87CEEB);`
2. Add color to the `ion-toolbar` tag

   example:

   `<ion-navbar color="blusky">`

   `</ion-ion-navbar>`

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix this problem,
just add to the css file those lines:

`.toolbar-background{
  background-color:#375faf;
}`

Comment: Overriding your Ionic variables would be a better option in my opion. Because you'll have it in a more consistent way and wouldn't have to add the color property into every page. More info : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: Thanks You! That helped!